# start scrolling when the UITextView hits a certain number of lines? swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, inputaccessoryview

So I'm making a messaging app, and I have an `inputAccessoryView` called `typingView`, which contains a `messageTextView: UITextView` and `sendButton: UIButton`. I have a separate class that is called `class InputAccessoryView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate`. This is my code for setting up the `inputAccessoryView`:

```
var typingView: InputAccessoryView!

lazy var typingViewContainer: UIView = {
    typingView = InputAccessoryView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: fakeTypingViewHeight.constant))
    return typingView
}()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return typingViewContainer
    }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

Then I add an observer to act on the event that the contentSize of the UITextView changes:

```
messageTextView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

I handle this correctly - every time the contentSize changes by *x* lines, I increase the height of the `typingView` by the height of *x* lines by calling `typingView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32647908/9477827).

Here is my code for recalculating the size:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let sizeToFitIn = CGSize(width: messageTextView.bounds.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let newSize = messageTextView.sizeThatFits(sizeToFitIn)
    let newHeight = newSize.height
    return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: newHeight)
}
```

Also, `messageTextView.isScrollEnabled = false`, because of [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18931531/9477827).

So it recalculates the height correctly every time the contentSize changes, but my question is: **If I want the UITextView to start scrolling at say, 5 lines, how would I do that?**

Comment: You need to change the contentSize but keep the frame the same at that point.

Comment: But then how would I find the `newHeight` of the UITextView at those number of lines?